# flv video flex core

Tags: video, apache-flex, air, flv

I have a flv video file.
I loaded the binary data of this flv file to memory by using

```
var myFile:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("AIR Test/video.flv");
var myFileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
myFileStream.open(myFile, FileMode.READ);
var **bytes**:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
myFileStream.readBytes(bytes);
myFileStream.close();
```

Now I'd like to change some header of this loaded flv in **bytes** memory variable, but after changing header, changed header was stored in **bytes** memory variable that is overwritten.

How can I play that flv file from this memory (**bytes** memory variable)?

Comment: You might want to tag this as air and/or adobe-air.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to save the bytes as a temp file and then play back from the local filesystem.

```
// write to temp file
var f:File = File.createTempFile();
var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
fs.open(f, FileMode.WRITE);
fs.writeBytes(bytes);
fs.close();

// play back
var display:VideoDisplay; // created somehow
display.source = f.url;
```

Not sure about some of the details (Does the temp file need a .flv extension?  Does the source URL need to be the native path or some such?) but that approach should work within AIR.